# jQuery Mobile Navigation error message in bottom

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I’m running a PhoneGap app with jQuery Mobile. I placed the html files inside www folder and its working just fine.

But the problem is that, when I’m trying to navigate pages. I’m getting following error in the bottom. Everything works just fine. I wanna know how to disable this annoying message.

[image]

Comment: Tell me, do you at any point reference href location with like this ../ or is your content above your index.html (first html) directory structure? Basically your first html must be inside www directory and all other content must be on a same level or deeper inside a directory structure.

Comment: @Gajotres I have hiddedn the div for now.